# GPUImage3 Unable to export video to Document Directory

Tags: ios, swift, gpu, gpuimage

I am using following source code to export filtered video to document directory but the exported file is corrupted/wrong.

Would you please go through following source and let me know where I am making mistake?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var renderView: RenderView!

    var movie:MovieInput!
    var writer:MovieOutput!
    var filter:LookupFilter!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!
        let movieURL = URL(string:"sample_iPod.m4v", relativeTo:bundleURL)!

        do {
            let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:true)
            let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("TestVideo.mov")

            movie = try MovieInput(url:movieURL, playAtActualSpeed:true)
            writer = try MovieOutput(URL: fileURL, size: Size(width: 100.0, height: 100.0))

            filter = LookupFilter()
            filter.lookupImage = PictureInput(image: UIImage(named: "Image")!)
            movie --> filter --> renderView
            movie.runBenchmark = true

            movie.addTarget(writer)
            movie.start()
            writer.startRecording()

            self.writer.finishRecording {
                print("Written")
            }

        } catch {
            print("Couldn't process movie with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: now you have 5 seconds .

```
     self.movie.addTarget(writer)
     self.movie.start()
     self.filter --> self.writer
    self.writer.startRecording()
    let interval = 5 // now you have 5 seconds .
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + interval) {
         self.writer.finishRecording {
             print("Written")
         }
 }
```

---

To solve your problem forward,
You should extract out the record logic. put that in a filter button action.

like the following demo code .

```
@IBAction func capture(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if (!isRecording) {
            do {
                self.isRecording = true
                let documentsDir = try FileManager.default.url(for:.documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:true)
                let fileURL = URL(string:"test.mp4", relativeTo:documentsDir)!
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at:fileURL)
                } catch {
                }

                movieOutput = try MovieOutput(URL:fileURL, size:Size(width:480, height:640), liveVideo:true)
                filter --> movieOutput!
                movieOutput!.startRecording()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Label not updating on the main thread, for some reason, so dispatching slightly after this
                    (sender as! UIButton).titleLabel!.text = "Stop"
                }
            } catch {
                fatalError("Couldn't initialize movie, error: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            movieOutput?.finishRecording{
                self.isRecording = false
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    (sender as! UIButton).titleLabel!.text = "Record"
                }
                self.movieOutput = nil
            }
        }
    }
```

---

You miss one line code `filter --> writer`

```
movie.addTarget(writer)
movie.start()
filter --> writer
writer.startRecording()

self.writer.finishRecording {
     print("Written")
}
```

Comment: Still there is issue in it. The exported file is zero bytes and it doesn't play filtered video.

Comment: Because your code logic is just to record and finish it immediately.

Comment: Hope my answer helps you a little, And you get the fun of GPU Image @Bhargav Soni

Comment: I have tried with your logic but there is still issue in same. Have you tested the code before posting it? Please understand the requirement.

I am not recording a video. Video is exist already in the project. I need to export it with filter. I do not understand why we need to delay the procedure.

I am working on following source code: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage3/tree/master/examples/iOS/SimpleMovieFilter

Comment: So sorry I have a little error. The time you startRecording, must have a distance (interval ) with the time you finishRecording.

Comment: Have you tested your logic? The issue still persists @dengApro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197259/discussion-between-dengapro-and-bhargav-soni).